# Is it possible to keep only numeric values and change all values into minutes at the same time in Excel or R?

Tags: r, excel, time, formula, numeric

I am trying to edit a table with data collected from a google form. In several columns there is data about weekly amounts of physical activity in minutes and hours. Except numeric values there is also text in cells representing minutes or hours of physical activity. The goal is to have only numeric values in these cells without the text and to have only minutes (i.e. hours need to be converted).

[Example of a column with respective data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRj0F.png)

I've tried with the following formula to get rid of the text which works just fine for this part of the problem: =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J52;"min";"");"h";"")

There is a problem when I am trying to nest the formula and get only minutes in cells as there are minutes (represented as: min), hours (represented as: h) and some values that have a > sign in front (e.g. > 4 hour is determined a priori to be 4:30, that is 270 minutes).

In order to potentially solve this in R, I am providing session info along with a reproducible example:
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRj0F.png) LC_COLLATE=Croatian_Croatia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Croatian_Croatia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Croatian_Croatia.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                      LC_TIME=Croatian_Croatia.1250
system code page: 1252

attached base packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRj0F.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRj0F.png) rstudioapi_0.13   knitr_1.33        magrittr_2.0.1    tidyselect_1.1.1  munsell_0.5.0     colorspace_2.0-0
[7] R6_2.5.0          rlang_0.4.11      fansi_0.4.2       dplyr_1.0.5       tools_4.0.4       grid_4.0.4
[13] gtable_0.3.0      xfun_0.22         tinytex_0.31      utf8_1.2.1        cli_2.5.0         DBI_1.1.1
[19] htmltools_0.5.1.1 ellipsis_0.3.1    digest_0.6.27     yaml_2.2.1        assertthat_0.2.1  tibble_3.1.1
[25] lifecycle_1.0.0   crayon_1.4.1      purrr_0.3.4       ggplot2_3.3.3     vctrs_0.3.7       evaluate_0.14
[31] glue_1.4.2        rmarkdown_2.7     compiler_4.0.4    pillar_1.6.0      generics_0.1.0    scales_1.1.1
[37] pkgconfig_2.0.3

```
data <- structure(list(id = c("100213", "100998", "100494", "100758", 
"100984", "100461", "100374", "140859", "150950", "140433", "200481", 
"200892", "300487", "300319", "400258", "400075", "200712", "120114", 
"500046", "500649", "600614", "700001", "300812", "700986", "800665", 
"700882", "800470", "400090", "900350", "700283", "600455", "800400", 
"100814", "700027", "600612", "30076", "500671", "200052", "600675", 
"800786", "110092", "800193", "800947", "500749", "800665", "400562", 
"150066", "200013", "700419", "400468", "600584", "ID 600366", 
"300379", "300035", "150346", "140860", "900508", "600751", "110825", 
"300848", "200990", "100237", "500137", "400751", "600347", "700289", 
"700000", "150320", "700319", "300643", "400871", "600963", "400295", 
"120120", "200875", "500209", "700380", "600646", "150415", "150415", 
"600640", "120999", "200693", "600626", "700003", "400493", "700849", 
"200544", "200001", "700801", "200084", "110951", "100371", "120114"
), vpa = c("0 min", "", "15 min", "0 min", "0 min", "45 min", 
"15 min", "0 min", "30 min", "30 min", "0 min", "0 min", "0 min", 
"0 min", "45 min", "3:00 h", "0 min", "", "15 min", "0 min", 
"1:00 h", "0 min", "45 min", "0 min", "0 min", "30 min", "1:00 h", 
"0 min", "1:00 h", "2:15 h", "30 min", "15 min", "0 min", "0 min", 
"0 min", "0 min", "0 min", "45 min", "1:00 h", "0 min", "1:30 h", 
"1:00 h", "0 min", "45 min", "0 min", "0 min", "0 min", "0 min", 
"15 min", "", "1:00 h", "0 min", "1:00 h", "30 min", "30 min", 
"30 min", "0 min", "30 min", "30 min", "45 min", "0 min", ">4 h", 
"15 min", "0 min", "45 min", "30 min", "30 min", "0 min", "1:30 h", 
"15 min", "45 min", "0 min", "15 min", "0 min", "0 min", "0 min", 
"0 min", "30 min", "2:00 h", "2:00 h", "15 min", "", "0 min", 
"0 min", "0 min", "0 min", "0 min", "0 min", "0 min", "0 min", 
"1:30 h", "15 min", "0 min", "4:00 h")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-94L))
```

The expected output would need to look like this:

```
data <- structure(list(id = c("100213", "100998", "100494", "100758", 
"100984", "100461", "100374", "140859", "150950", "140433", "200481", 
"200892", "300487", "300319", "400258", "400075", "200712", "120114", 
"500046", "500649", "600614", "700001", "300812", "700986", "800665", 
"700882", "800470", "400090", "900350", "700283", "600455", "800400", 
"100814", "700027", "600612", "30076", "500671", "200052", "600675", 
"800786", "110092", "800193", "800947", "500749", "800665", "400562", 
"150066", "200013", "700419", "400468", "600584", "ID 600366", 
"300379", "300035", "150346", "140860", "900508", "600751", "110825", 
"300848", "200990", "100237", "500137", "400751", "600347", "700289", 
"700000", "150320", "700319", "300643", "400871", "600963", "400295", 
"120120", "200875", "500209", "700380", "600646", "150415", "150415", 
"600640", "120999", "200693", "600626", "700003", "400493", "700849", 
"200544", "200001", "700801", "200084", "110951", "100371", "120114"
), vpa_2 = c("0", "", "15", "0", "0", "45", 
"15", "0", "30", "30", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "45", "180", "0", "", "15", "0", 
"60", "0", "45", "0", "0", "30", "60", 
"0", "60", "135", "30", "15", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "45", "60", "0", "90", 
"60", "0", "45", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"15", "", "60", "0", "60", "30", "30", 
"30", "0", "30", "30", "45", "0", "270", 
"15", "0", "45", "30", "30", "0", "90", 
"15", "45", "0", "15", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "30", "120", "120", "15", "", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"90", "15", "0", "240")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -94L))
```

Comment: Extract the number; then determine the multiplier depending on whether the cell contained "h", "min", or ">"

Comment: If you want to solve this in R, it would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I am not sure how to determine whether the cell contained "h", "min", or ">" after I am left with just the numeric value

Comment: You check the original cell, using `SEARCH` or `FIND`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doable using base R. I put the solution first:

```
# make a copy of your input data
test <- data

# remove the letters from the time string
for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
  test$vpa[[i]] <- gsub("min|h"," ",test$vpa[[i]])
}

# if a string is in the hour unit (strings appearing as "xx:yy"), replace its value with the calculated minutes
for (i in 1:nrow(test)){
  if (grepl(":",test$vpa[[i]]) == TRUE){
    test$vpa[[i]] <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(test$vpa[[i]],":"))[1])*60 + as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(test$vpa[[i]],":"))[2])
  }
}

# check results
# The result "test" will look like your expected output
print(test)
```

I am not using any packages here, but you may need some knowledge of `gsub`,`grepl` and `str_split` to understand what I did. Basically, my logic is to play around the `strings`.

Comment: Your solution worked for me in this case, only value that wasn't converted and isn't covered by this solution is >4 h but the code is now clearer to me and I will try to replicate a similar solution on the rest of the data. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonioMartinko Sorry, I did not notice there is a cell with ">4h"! Sure, you can learn from the logic above to edit the solution. But if ">4h" is the only unsolved issue, and there is not anything else like ">5h",">6h". You can just solve it by test$vpa[grepl(">4",test$vpa) == TRUE] <- ">240". It does not require a for loop.

Comment: thank you once again, I've worked it out and this works great for my dataset.